# Autoincrement does not work PostgreSQL - Java EE APP

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have application in which I have autoincrement for PK Id. I had to add other autoincremented column and I used liquibase to make it work - liquibase created sequence for auto increment. When I make insert from query tool or when i do not map this field in entity and make persist autoincrement works. But when I add :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "next_value", nullable=false, unique=true)
private Long nextValue;
```

I get an ugly error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: empty value in the "next_value" column violates the limit of the required value
```

What is wrong here?

EDIT:

My liquibase changeset to add this column and make it autoincrement:

```
<addColumn tableName="table">
      <column name="next_value" type="number"/>
    </addColumn>
<addAutoIncrement
        columnDataType="number"
        columnName="next_value"
        incrementBy="1"
        startWith="1"
        tableName="table"/>
<sql>select setval('table_next_value_seq', (select cast(current_value+1 as bigint) from gapless_sequence), false)</sql>
```

setval was used to start it not from 1

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question.

Comment: IDENTITY does not mean a SEQUENCE. It means a column that is generated in the database ... like AUTO_INCREMENT or SERIAL. Not posting what your schema is makes the question guesswork ...

Comment: @BillyFrost: `identity` columns in Postgres are implemented using a sequence (the same way as a `serial` column)

Comment: How something is "implemented" internal to a database is beyond the scope of JPA. A JPA provider will require an IDENTITY COLUMN, end of. Until the OP posts the DDL for their table, and what SQL was invoked on insertion then it's all kinda pointless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable insertable and updatable false

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "next_value", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false,updatable = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess it should change table in db

```
ALTER TABLE tblName(
nextValue LONG NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
```

....